# Andengine Box2D Explosion

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics

i want to make explosion effect after the player throws the handgernade, explosion means blast like the bodies near the thrown handgernade will randomly jump.......
here is the example

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXCJsV3oAkw

how can i get this effect..Plz help

Answer (score 1):

Just create an animated sprite using andengine and then (maybe) use the physics extension to throw some shrapnel (also some sprites).

btw: If you want 2 have code, you maybe should start off and show us something we could work with ;)

Comment: My dear i think you are misunderstanding my question..my question was is there any method in andengine that if i want to create an explosion effect that when i animate the animated sprite of explosion the near by dynamic physics bodies feel its impact and fall down on ground if they are standing

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to accomplish. There is no method that would do this for you so I suggest you look which bodies are close to the blast and then apply some linear impulse to them. The impulse should probably have a vector between the body and the explosion. As to the force of the impulse, you will have to change it according to the distance from the blast.